# @Path issue using Jersey 2.x bundle

Tags: java, jax-rs, web.xml, jersey-2.0, jdeveloper

I am trying to implement basic hello application using JAXRS and Jersey 2.x bundle,but facing problem with @Path.  When i am using Jersey 1.x library @Path as well as hello world application is working fine.

Steps i followed :

1. Jdev 11g Release 2
2. Created a Standalone Java Project --> included Jersey 2.x libs ( Check below Image )
3. Created a java class with annotation @Path

   ```
   import javax.ws.rs.GET;
   import javax.ws.rs.Path;

   @Path("/hello")
   public class TestJerseyBundle {
       public TestJerseyBundle() {
           super();
       }

       @GET
       public String getStatus(){
           return "hello Jersey 2.x";
       }
   }
   ```

Now there is a warning in @Path. When we put cursor on @Path it shows " jersey servlet is not configured in web.xml "

4. By the help of Code assist it created default web.xml

Please check below image

By default it configured com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer which is part of Jersey 1.x bundle. But in my application i am using Jersey 2.x. So i modified web.xml with below information :

Default and modified web.xml in Image

[image: Default and modified web.xml in Image]

Now warning symbol under servlet-class element has gone now.

5. Before and After web.xml change i can see the same problem in @Path
6. I tried to deploy my application with @Path problem : So application deployed successfully

When i hit URL like : localhost:port/RestAppJersey-RestAppOD-context-root/hello  it is throwing 404 error.

Can someone suggest how to use Jersey 2.x libs to develope RESTful web services in Jdev 11g Release 2. ( I tried with latest lib version also jersey 2.24 still facing same issue ) .

And by default why it is configuring  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer  in web.xml ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't post images of code! Include the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `url-pattern` of `/jersey/*`. So that need to be part of the URL you try to access.

```
localhost:port/RestAppJersey-RestAppOD-context-root/jersey/hello
```

As far as your IDE problem, I don't know. I don't use that IDE

Comment: i used http://localhost:7101/RestAppJersey-RestApp-context-root/jersey/hello  . Got 404 error . 
Below information i got it from weblogic server console :

Target Application WADL -- http://localhost:7101/RestAppJersey-RestApp-context-root/application.wadl

Target URL -- http://localhost:7101/RestAppJersey-RestApp-context-root/hello

Comment: Sample app: Jersey 2.x in Jdev 11g
Step 1:
    `@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}`
Step 2: 
    `@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // register root resource
        classes.add(HelloResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}`
Step 3: Edit above web.xml register MyApplication in init-param